# Potentially missing Plan data from Plan Finder API

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

There have been observed discrepancies between the list of plans retrieved from Plan Finder API (via getIFPPlanQuotes call) and people's independent knowledge of which plans are offered in a particular location.  Some of these examples are documented here: http://hhs.ddod.us/wiki/Use_Case_28:_Verify_accuracy_of_healthcare.gov_Plan_Finder.  Note that the data is consistently missing from both the API and Plan Finder website for consumers.

I wanted to see if anyone else had noticed similar issues.  Does anyone know if the issue might be just a matter of plans not submitting their data to the CMS Enterprise Portal?  If so, is there a systematic way to account for missing data?